# Validar ciertos datos de una cadena

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio, la verdad básico, pero que aun así no doy con lo que estoy haciendo mal...

Acá les dejo un pedazo de mi código:

```
let pin2 = pin.split('');
const caracter= pin2.some((element) => typeof (parseInt(element)) === 'NaN');
console.log(caracter)
```

Supuestamente yo, debería retornar true, pero me devuelve `false`. En el código, el usuario ingresa una cadena y yo estoy tratando de verificar si hay elementos que no son números.

Answer (score 2):

Estás tratando de comparar `NaN`, este elemento no se puede identificar, hay una opción llamada `isNaN` que te dice si algo es equivalente a `NaN`

```
let pin2 = pin.split('');
const caracter= pin2.some((element) => (isNaN(parseInt(element))));
console.log(caracter)
```

Además, el método `parseInt` te da un número y no lo puedes comparar con string ya que dará `false`

Comment: El problema no es que `NaN` no se pueda identificar (que tampoco entiendo muy bien qué quieres decir con eso). El problema radica en que `typeof NaN` es `"number"`. Dejo [aquí](https://javascriptrefined.io/nan-and-typeof-36cd6e2a4e43) un *link* que considero últil.

Comment: Gracias, apenas estoy empezando en JS, no sabia ese detalle de NaN. La funcion dentro de 'some' lo que hace es verificar si lo que esta dentro del array, retorna 'NaN', si es asi, lo compara y deberia dar true, pero daba falso, por eso, porque NaN === 'number'.